# UNION Query to update Table

Tags: ms-access, union

This is my UNION Query

```
INSERT INTO Master (Player, Won, Lost)
SELECT Player, Sum(Won), Sum(Lost) FROM (
    SELECT First([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner]) AS Player,
    Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner]) AS Won,
    0 AS Lost
    FROM [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016]
    GROUP BY [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner]
    HAVING (((Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner])) > 1))

    UNION

    SELECT First([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser]) AS Player,
    0 as Won,
    Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser]) AS Lost
    FROM [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016]
    GROUP BY [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser]
    HAVING (((Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser])) > 1))
)
GROUP BY Player
```

This query does everything that I want, except of course 1 thing.
When the records in my MASTER DATA RESULTS 2013 -2016 is updated with new records and I run my query as here above my MASTER table is all screwed up.
Instead of updating the table the query just adds again all the players with the new numbers.

How can I make sure that the query isn't adding lines to the MASTER table but just update the Won and Lost fields in the MASTER table?

I've played around with unique values and UPDATE but without succes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the table directly using query with UNION or GROUP BY, such king queries are not updateable. You can or delete all rows from Master table before inserting new rows, or if the Master table contains information, which should be kept as is, just update few rows with players from your union query, insert the data from this query to temporary table and then update master table by query with joined Master and temporary tables.

The query for updating Master table by data from MasterTemp table should be like this:

```
UPDATE Master INNER JOIN MasterTemp ON Master.Player = MasterTemp.Player 
SET Master.Won = [MasterTemp].[Won], Master.Lost = [MasterTemp].[Lost];
```

Comment: I'm seem to struggle with this. So I've used the UNION Query to get my information an put it into MASTERTEMP table. I than tried to JOIN the MASTER and MASTERTEMP table. This works but the query don't update the colums Won and Lost in the Masterfile, it just adds new records